# How to reference the tableview of a datasource?

Tags: python, ios, uitableview

I‘m using a tableview with a listdatasource to select items from a list. I used pyui designer and I have defined an action for the tableview. Within the code of the action I want to reference another subview of my GUI.
This is the code:

```
def act_select(sender):
    global mysql, mydictsql
    sv = sender.superview
    s, r = sender.selected_row
    k, sql = mydictsql.items[r]
    sv['txt_vw_sql'].text = sql
    mysql = sql
```

However, sender is not the tableview but the listdatasource. Consequently, it has no attribute superview which leaves me with an error.
How can I build a chain of references like

```
sv = sender.parent.superview
```

which doesn’t work because sender has no attribute parent. I couldn’t  find a hint about the correct reference.

Comment: What is `sender`?

Comment: When you use the pyui designer in Pythonista you define a callback routine for the subviews like a button or an input. On an event like ‘button pressed’ the callback routine is called with a reference (sender) to the corresponding subview.